# How can I change in Cinemachine the Game Window Guides center to be on the player center?

Tags: unity-game-engine

On the game view on the left the yellow small square is on the player foot and the whole rectangle on the bottom is down out the view.

How can I move up the yellow small square of the Game Window Guides to be on the player center and that the bottom of the Game Window Guides rectangle will be fit in the game view so I can control it change it's size ?

[image: Cinemachine]

In this screenshot I'm using paint to add circle/s to explain more what do I mean the yellow small square and what do I mean by fit the size and that is out at the bottom :

I use blue circle to show the yellow small square I meant and blue rectangle to show the bottom that is getting out the Game view :

[image: Cinemachine]

How can I change in Cinemachine the Game Window Guides center to be on the player center ?
The small yellow square I think and I want to be on the character center body not on his foot.

And on the bottom I can't drag the Game Window Guides since it's out on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Under Middle Rig property, change the y-axis from 0 to 1.